# how to get mouse position of a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
documentDOM.addEventListener("click", new EventListener() {
                            public void handleEvent(Event evt) {

                                if (evt.getType().equals("click")) {
                                    System.out.println("hello");
                                    MouseEvent mouseIvent = (MouseEvent) evt;
                                    int screenX = mouseIvent.getXOnScreen();
                                    int screenY = mouseIvent.getYOnScreen();
                                    System.out.println("screen(X,Y) = " + screenX + "\t" + screenY);
                               }
                            }
                        }, true);
```

I need to locate a specific pixel location on my Java application. This Java application can be windowed or maximized window.

My code somehow doesn't return the integers. this event does fire as hello message is spit out.

Comment: You have to add a `MouseListener` on your component to listen for mouse events on the component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is that you must add a [MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the component which will report the click locations:

```
public class LocationPrinter extends MouseAdapter {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    panel.addMouseListener(new LocationPrinter());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Location Window");
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    int screenX = me.getXOnScreen();
    int screenY = me.getYOnScreen();
    System.out.println("screen(X,Y) = " + screenX + "," + screenY);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//http://www.geekssay.com/java-program-to-get-mouse-coordinates/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class TestInner {
 private JFrame f;
 private JTextField tf;
 
 public TestInner () {
 f = new JFrame ("Inner classes example");
 tf = new JTextField(30);
 }
 
 class MyMouseMotionListener extends MouseMotionAdapter {
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
 String s = "Mouse dragging: X = "+ e.getX()
 + " Y = " + e.getY();
 tf.setText(s);
 }
 }
 
 public void launchFrame() {
 JLabel label = new JLabel("Click and drag the mouse");
 // add componers to the frame
 f.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 f.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 // Add a listener that uses an Inner class
 f.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseMotionListener());
 f.addMouseListener(new MouseClickHandler());
 // Size the frame and make it visible
 f.setSize(300, 200);
 f.setVisible(true);
}
 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
 TestInner obj = new TestInner();
 obj.launchFrame();
 }
}
 
class MouseClickHandler extends MouseAdapter {
 
// We just need the mouseClick handler, so we use
 // an adapter to avoid having to write all the
 // event handler methods
 
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
 // Do stuff with the mouse click...
 }
}
```